# Customer group price

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group

I want to make a customer group in magento where the customers in that group will have to pay 10% extra on top of the product price, is there a simple way (like adding discounts for customer groups) to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by setting the following:

- Regular pricing is 100% and that customer group gets regular price
- All other customer groups get special pricing at 10% off

You could do this with either the product pricing or with catalog price rules. The former is preferable as catalog price rules present the prices as a strikethrough discount.